# Using LINQ and Lambda expression to assign value in ViewModel Object Class in C#

Tags: c#, viewmodel

I want to assign value from LIST to another Class Object ' _People.People' in ViewModel with loop as choice 1  _uof.PeopleRepository.GetAll() gives me PeopleEntity Object data

### ViewModel

```
public class PeopleViewModel
{
    public PeopleEntity People { get; set; }
    public PeopleUnitEntity PeopleUnit { get; set; }
}
```

### Implantation class

```
 public override IList<PeopleViewModel> GetPeopleByPersonCode(int PersonCode)
    {
        IList<PeopleViewModel> _People = null;

        using (var _uof = new FES_UOF())
        {
             _People = _uof.PeopleRepository.GetAll().Where(x => x.PERSON_CODE == PersonCode).ToList();

        //I need help here; want to put above list value to _people.People object 
        }

        return _People;
    }
```

### People ViewModel

```
 [Table("FES.PEOPLE")]
public class PeopleEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int PERSON_CODE { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string FORENAME { get; set; }

    [StringLength(240)]
    public string MIDDLE_NAMES { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string SURNAME { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string PREVIOUS_SURNAME { get; set; }

    [StringLength(8)]
    public string TITLE { get; set; }
//remaining code
```

### 2nd update question

I have achieve to get data in viewModel Object but my question still stands there how I achieve this i.e. by using Lambda expression without loop.

working transaction as following;

```
_PeopleModel = (from pl in _uof.PeopleRepository.GetAll()
                 where pl.PERSON_CODE == PersonCode
                 select new PeopleViewModel { People = pl}).ToList();
```

### Output GetPeopleByPersonCode

[image]

I have tried like following but its not working;

```
var queryResult = new PeopleViewModel { People =  _uof.PeopleRepository.GetAll().Where(x => x.PERSON_CODE == PersonCode)  };
```

Comment: What is the response like when you called GetPeopleByPersonCode method?

Comment: look section after 2nd update in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found answer to do from both LINQ and Lambda

```
 public override IList<PeopleViewModel> GetPeopleByPersonCode(int PersonCode)
    {
        IList<PeopleViewModel> _PeopleModel = null;
        IList<PeopleViewModel> _PeopleModel_b = null;

        using (var _uof = new FES_UOF())
        {
            _PeopleModel_b =   _uof.PeopleRepository.GetAll().Where(x => x.PERSON_CODE == PersonCode).Select( pl => new PeopleViewModel { People = pl}).ToList();

          //or
            _PeopleModel_b = (from pl in _uof.PeopleRepository.GetAll()
                              where pl.PERSON_CODE == PersonCode
                              select new PeopleViewModel { People = pl}).ToList();
        }

        return _PeopleModel;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to convert the linq style to lambda style. If so you can do something like this:

```
_PeopleModel = _uof.PeopleRepository.GetAll()
.Where (x= > x.PERSON_CODE == PersonCode)
.Select(pl => new PeopleViewModel { People = pl})
.ToList();
```

I'm saying this because in your print screen you have results in the People property.